# HTTP STATUS 404: The requested resource (/first.jsp) is not available(Apache Tomcat+JDK)

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm getting this error after running jsp program:
HTTP STATUS 404: The requested resource (/first.jsp) is not available

I've followed the same procedure i.e to copy WEB-IBF under project folder etc.

```
location: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\webapps\aman\first.jsp

link:http://localhost:8080/aman/first.jsp
```

I've checked the port number also under server file, it's 8080.
Apache is starting server correctly, even checked it under Control Panel.
I've copied WEB-INF in correct way etc.
After googling I found that I should check log file, but there is no log file under folder

```
"C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs"
```

Started with jsp and written this small code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>post:ApacheTomcat</title>
</head>
<body>

<%-- START --%>
<%
    out.println("first program in JSP.");
%>
<%-- END --%>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Comment: check web.xml here: http://pastebin.com/F8BVYVeZ

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. shutdown your tomcat server.
2. delete aman folder from directory work/catalina/localhost
3. start tomcat and view your page in browser.

**Dont delete work folder or any other just delete aman folder
**Work folder is available in tomcat installation directory

If you are using eclipse then find and delete the following folder then restart eclipse and re-add your server in eclipse IDE and then try to run your application with newly added server environment.

eclipse_workspace_folder/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core

Comment: First check your web.xml file, if everything in web.xml file correct then try above solution

Comment: I even created simple first.jsp in ROOT folder, the localhost:8080 link is working, but http://localhost:8080/first.jsp is not working.        I'm not using any IDE like Eclipse. Where is this work/catalina/localhost?? I'm using Windows 7

Comment: In my case work folder is in tomcat installation folder: C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\work

Comment: I just saw your xml file. you don't have to change your xml file just delete the aman folder from work directory. If you get the error after deleting aman folder then I suggest you to reinstall tomcat. I had same problem it was resolved by reinstalling tomcat/deleting work folder.

Comment: If you installed tomcat using exe file with default directory then your tomcat will be in "C:\Program Files" directory, you will find work directory inside tomcats directory. (If you are using older tomcat version [i.e. 5th of earlier version] then i would like to know which version you are using [tomcat 6 and onward releases have changed their directory structure])

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, I guess the problem may be under installation of so many softwares relate to server handling on mys system(MySql, Apache, SQL SERVER, Microsoft VS 2010, 2012 etc). I just resolved the problem by installing Windows7 under VirtualBox...Now  it is running correctly. I'm working as a freelancer on 2-3 projects so I need all these softwares :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Delete the folder under work/Catalina/{you}
2. Open you jsp file in your web browser